# Изменить URL

Tags: url, ajax

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы ещё и url менялся на registration.php? Заранее спасибо, что-то вообще не понимаю.

```
   $(document).ready(function()     
        {
            $('#to_register').click(function()
            {

       $.ajax({  
                    url: "registration.php",
                    type : "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'html',    
                    success: function(html){  
                        $(".container").html(html); 
    $("#xr_splash_progress").remove();
    $("#xr_splash").remove();                       
                    }  
                });

            });     
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы без перезагрузки **сменить** адрес в браузере можно использовать `History API`, а именно [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/#The_pushState().C2.A0method). Само собой, это будет работать только в браузерах, которые поддерживают `HTML5`.

Простейший пример:

```
var redirect = '/registration.php';
history.pushState('', '', redirect);
```

За большим идите по [ссылке](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/) и знакомьтесь с деталями.

А если просто и скучно **перейти** на новый адрес, то:

```
var redirect = '/registration.php';
window.location = redirect;
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё вариант: обрабатывать хэш адреса (window.location.hash) - это символы после # в адресной строке. Чаще всего они используются для перехода к якорям, но имеют и другое назначение.
Вот пример функций для получения переменных хэша:

```
$.extend({
    getHashVars: function(){
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('#') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
            if (hashes[i].indexOf('=') > -1){
                hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
        }
        return vars;
    },
    getHashVar: function(name){
        return $.getHashVars()[name];
    },
    setHashVar: function(name, value){
        check = $.getHashVar(name);
        if (typeof check != 'undefined' && check != ''){
            window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace(name+'='+check, name+'='+value);
        }else{
            if (window.location.hash.length == 0){
                window.location.hash = name+'='+value;
            }else{
                window.location.hash += '&'+name+'='+value;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Пример получения переменной

```
var X = $.getHashVar('X');
```

Пример установки переменной

```
$.setHashVar('X', 'some value');
```

При этом на каждой странице должен быть обработчик текущего значения хэша. Что-то типа этого:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //получаем значение из переменной хэша page
    currentPage = $.getHashVar('page');
    if (typeof currentPage != 'undefined'){
        //если в переменной что-то есть - загружаем соответствующую страницу
        $.ajax({  
            url: currentPage+".php",
            type : "POST",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'html',    
            success: function(html){  
                $(".container").html(html); 
                $("#xr_splash_progress").remove();
                $("#xr_splash").remove();                       
            }  
        });
    }
});
```

Т.е., если в адресной строке будет что-то типа http://mysite.com/#page=registration, то загрузится содержимое страницы registration.php.

Ну и соответственно при асинхронной загрузке новой страницы нужно устанавливать переменную хэша (в данном случае page) в соответствующее значение.

**Добавлено позднее**

А лучше особо не заморачиваться и использовать это http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/.

У самого сейчас в разработке проект с асинхронной навигацией, буду использовать данный плагин.