# Смена URL в адресной строке браузера.

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. Имеется код, который выводит картинки из папки в случайном порядке.

```
 <script> 
      $('#prev').click(function(){
      current_image --;
      hideControls(current_image);

      $('#current_image').attr('src', images[current_image]);

      var link = window.location.hostname + '/index.php?';
      link += 'pic=' + images[current_image];
      $('#link').html('<a href="http://' + link + '">' + link + '</a>');
      });
  </script>
```

Который выводиться в браузер при помощи данного кода.

```
&nbsp;<a href="#" id="prev" style="display: none;"></a>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы у меня выводился URL картинки, в браузерной строке без обновления страницы?

Comment: [History API](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/)

Answer (score 4):

Если выполнить очень сложный поиск по сайту, с использованием фразы "адрес без перезагрузки", можно найти вот что:

- [Изменение адресной строки по клику без перезагрузки страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/142384/) (обратите внимание на ответ)
- [Динамическое изменение адреса в адресной строке браузера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/165479/)
- [Как изменить адресную строку браузера без перезагрузки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/85380/)

А если еще что-то поискать, то можно еще найти:

- [Изменение url в адресной строке браузера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/136860/)
- [Изменить URL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/127319/)